# List of shared pointers in QProperties

Tags: c++, qt

**How to create qt property with list of shared pointers type?**

I want to create `QProperty` with type `QList<std::shared_ptr<A>>`. `A` is a class derived from `QObject`( that's why i'm using pointers).
But unfortunately I get an error:

> QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'QList' for property.

This is my properties declaration:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QList<AddressTableModel::Ptr> addressTableModel READ getAddressTableModel WRITE setAddressTableModel)
Q_PROPERTY(QList<GroupsTableModel::Ptr>  groupsTableModel READ getGroupsTableModel WRITE setGroupsTableModel)
Q_PROPERTY(QList<UsersAndGroupsTableModel::Ptr>  usersAndGroupsTableModel READ getUsersAndGroupsTableModel WRITE setUsersAndGroupsTableModel)
Q_PROPERTY(QList<UsersTableModel::Ptr>  usersTableModel READ getUsersTableModel WRITE setUsersTableModel)
```

I've already tried to register my classes with `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QList<UsersTableModel::Ptr>);
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QList<GroupsTableModel::Ptr>);
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QList<UsersAndGroupsTableModel::Ptr>);
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QList<AddressTableModel::Ptr>);
```

*SomeClass::Ptr is a `typedef` of `shared_ptr` for the related class*

But I still get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `QVariantList` form these purposes in the tie with Q_DECLARE_SMART_POINTER_METATYPE:

```
Q_DECLARE_SMART_POINTER_METATYPE(std::shared_ptr)


class MyClassWithProperties : public QObject
{
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariantList addressTableModel READ getAddressTableModel WRITE setAddressTableModel)
};
```

Then just make some shared pointers:

```
MyClassWithProperties obj;

auto firstObject = std::make_shared<QObject>();
auto secondObject = std::make_shared<QObject>();
QVariantList values = { QVariant::fromValue(firstObject), QVariant::fromValue(secondObject) };

obj.setProperty("addressTableModel", values)
```

Remember to derive your shared-ptr value type from QObject.